# Modify URL with .htaccess [#Q1.]

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I want to modify the URL on my server using `.htaccess` but I'm facing some issues.

Checkout [#Q2. here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66154848/14817809).

**Rule #1:**

> `https://example.com/site/index.php`
>
> `https://example.com/site/`
>
> should get converted to short url.
>
> `https://example.com/`

**Rule #2:**

> `https://example.com/`
>
> should load full url without expanding.
>
> `https://example.com/site/index.php`.

**Rule #3:**

> `https://example.com/a/site/index.php`
>
> `https://example.com/b/site/index.php`
>
> `https://example.com/a/site/`
>
> `https://example.com/b/site/`
>
> should get converted to short url.
>
> `https://example.com/a/`
>
> `https://example.com/b/`

**Note that:** I want to remove the `site` folder from URL's and I don't know to write `.htaccess`, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please show your current .htaccess. Also are `/site/` or `/a/site/` real directories?

Comment: My current `.htaccess` is empty, I just tried the solution from the question that I mentioned, and yes `localhost/site/` and `localhost/a/site/` are real directories and I will change the names in the future.

Comment: @Arghadip, For `Rule #4: should not block other URL's` could you please do provide some samples which urls you are talking about here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try these rules in your site root .htaccess (assuming there are no other .htaccess in sib directories):

```sh
RewriteEngine On

# matches /site/ or /site/index.php or 
# /a/site/index.php or /b/site/index.php
# captures a/ or b/ or an empty string in %1
# redirects to /a/ or /b/ or /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([ab]/|)site/(?:index\.php)?[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=302,NE]

# matches a/ or b/ or empty (landing page)
# rewrites to a/site/index.php or b/site/index.php or site/index.php
RewriteRule ^([ab]/)?$ $1site/index.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```