# Modify URL with .htaccess [#Q2.]

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I want to modify the URL on my server using `.htaccess` but I'm facing some issues.

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66107862/14817809) I described all the modifications I wanted. I want add some new rules along side the [previous rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66108124/14817809).

```
RewriteEngine On

# matches /site/ or /site/index.php or 
# /a/site/index.php or /b/site/index.php
# captures a/ or b/ or an empty string in %1
# redirects to /a/ or /b/ or /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([ab]/|)site/(?:index\.php)?[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=302,NE]

# matches a/ or b/ or empty (landing page)
# rewrites to a/site/index.php or b/site/index.php or site/index.php
RewriteRule ^([ab]/)?$ $1site/index.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

**New Rule #1:**

> `https://example.com/site/index.php` (already does)
>
> `https://example.com/site/index` (does not)
>
> `https://example.com/site/` (already does)
>
> should get converted to short url.
>
> `https://example.com/`

**New Rule #2:**

> `https://example.com/a/site/index.php` (already does)
>
> `https://example.com/a/site/index` (does not)
>
> `https://example.com/a/site/` (already does)
>
> should get converted to short url.
>
> `https://example.com/a/`

**New Rule #3:**

> `https://example.com/site/any.php` (does not)
>
> `https://example.com/site/any` (does not)
>
> should get converted to short url.
>
> `https://example.com/any/`

**New Rule #4:**

> `https://example.com/any/` (does not)
>
> should load full url without expanding.
>
> `https://example.com/site/any.php`

**Note that:** The `any.php` is dynamic, means it's a `([\w]+).php` and I don't know to write `.htaccess`, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

# matches /site/ or /site/index.php or 
# /a/site/index.php or /b/site/index.php
# captures a/ or b/ or an empty string in %1
# redirects to /a/ or /b/ or /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([ab]/|)site/(?:index(?:\.php)?)?[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=302,NE]

# removes site/ from URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+site/(\S+?)(?:\.php)?/?\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [L,R=302,NE]

# remove .php from all URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=302,NE,L]

# add trailing slash to all URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=302,NE]

# matches a/ or b/ or empty (landing page)
# rewrites to a/site/index.php or b/site/index.php or site/index.php
RewriteRule ^([ab]/)?$ $1site/index.php [L,NC]

# adds .php internally to /any
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# adds .php internally to /site/any
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/site/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ site/$1.php [L]
```

There are comments before each rule to clarify what it does.